# Non-global variables everytime I call a module

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multithreading, variables

These variables are in a module.exports file, and when I call the module multiple times, each instance shares the values. I don't want them to share values, each time I call the module, I want each call to have its own cycle number, original, newprod, etc.. Like multithreading.

I am in NodeJS on a Mac

`cycle = 0;
var original = [];
var newprod = [];
var proxylist = [];`

NEW EDIT -----

I added a `new` constructor when calling and it didn't work. Not sure whats the problem they are still sharing the variables. Here is my code.

config.sites.forEach(function (site) {
  var mod = require(`./src/monitor`).init,
    mod1 = new mod(site);
});

Comment: Can't you make your module export a function?

Comment: I did, but i'm trying to make the variables in the function unique to each call.

Comment: A module is not called, it is loaded. Once - there is only one module. If you want to call something, put the code in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to prevent overriding variables, you should **[limit them to a specific scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)**. A scope can be a function, or class.

For your case, you can create a class to maintain the variables isolated in each instance and then creating methods for updating their values. [Here's an example I found](https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/fa62af0a2c57f5ef54226cae2258b38d).

Also, from es2015 [you can create classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) like in most languages.

Comment: Thank you, I did limit them to a scope (function). But I am calling that function multiple times.

Comment: I see but have you tried saving the result every time you call it? var a = something() and then access using a method like in the link I put: var originalA = a.getOriginal() ?